# How to Demo Automated Tests

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, test-strategy, qa-process

I `automate tests` based on test plans written by `manual testers`.

I would like to `demo` the `automated tests` to the authors of the `manual test plans` to ensure, that I've implemented the test correctly and to promote collaboration.

While I could have them stand behind me as they watch the test run on my machine, I was thinking it may also be helpful if there were some way I record the running test (create a video), that they could watch (including pausing) at their desks to review along side of the written test plans.

I would likely `record` in `debug mode`, so that the test wouldn't run at normal speed (too fast). Also, it would be great if there were a way to `add informational captions`?

Are there tools, that could help me in this?

**UPDATE #1:**

It is apparently called `screencasting` software (what I'm looking for). I'm finding some now online, that might get the job done for me such as `TechSmith's SnagIt`.

Comment: Personally, video "evidence" isn't of use to me.  I have no idea if your test is actually checking anything, or if it's just navigating through blindly.  Show me a test run that actually finds defects.  Ideally, let me put the unit under test in a state where I'd expect tests to fail, run the automation against it, and prove to me that the automation catches defects.

Comment: Screencasting is super-useful to demo web tests and issues. Here is a good [list of free screencasting tools](https://a9t9.com/blog/screencasting/). I use Loom.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out, [Snagit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snagit)

**It is a very good idea to record a video as in a live demo, there is a high chance something could go wrong, what I suggest is:**

- Prepare a live demo, maybe a highlighted version of your full demo, without excessive waiting so that people will not get bored.
- Please consider providing caption by speaking to your customers, imagine how difficult it will be to watch your demo and read subtitles at the same time.
- Bring a program logic flowchart as well, in a separate A3 paper, which can be used as a poster.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like videos as proof of concept, I tend to quickly loose concentration and miss the point.

When my team needed to present something (software in our case, but the idea is the same) we've built a hollow prototype with most of the functionality and screens but with no logic behind it, no database, no connectivity is needed, the data is static and mocked etc.

This let the end users actually play with the product and get the look and feel of it.

Screen sharing using Skype for example is also a good idea, since you can keep your audience attention, answer questions or go back and forth in the presentation.

Comment: Thank you! I am inspired by the answers I have received to my initial question. So thought provoking. The part of your answer specifically I am focusing on the value of allowing users to "play" and "get the look and feel." This is so helpful. It is very difficult for many (most?) to really know what they want until they see it!  Thank you again for this and your other feedback.